# Junit - Spring - Testing Collections

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, junit

Can you please advise who to test Collection with JUnit 4 and Spring MVC?

Controller

```
@Controller
public class PersonController {
    @Autowired
    private PersonService personService;

    @RequestMapping(value = {"/", "/index"}, method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String getPerson(Model model) {
        model.addAttribute("personData", personService.getPerson);
        return "personPage";
    }
}
```

Testing a Person class can be done by:

```
public class TestPersonController {

    @Mock
    private PersonService personService;

    @InjectMocks
    private PersonController personController;

    private MockMvc mockMvc;

    @Before
    public void setup() {
        MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
        mockMvc = MockMvcBuilders.standaloneSetup(personController).build();
    }

    @Test
    public void testGetPerson() throws Exception {
        when(personService.getPerson(1L)).thenReturn(new Person(1L, "StackOverflow"));

        mockMvc.perform(get("/person/{id}", 1L))
                .andExpect(status().isOk())
                .andExpect(view().name("personPage"))
                .andExpect(model().attribute("personData",
                                             allOf(hasProperty("id", is(1L)),
                                                   hasProperty("name", is("StackOverflow")))));
    }
}
```

But I am not able to figure out how to test if perService.getPerson return List!

Comment: Let's see your controller.

Comment: Also, what have you tried for testing a `List` returned object?

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis - I have added the Controller code. Sorry, I have no idea how to do it and I tried to run the same Junit code with the Collection and (as expected) that failed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'd test it the same way you are doing now but using corresponding `Matcher` instances to check `Collection` elements.

Assuming you had a handler method like

```
@RequestMapping(value = { "/persons",}, method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String getPersons(Model model) {
    model.addAttribute("personList", personService.getPersons());
    return "personsPage";
}
```

you simply need to change your mock to return something else

```
when(personService.getPersons()).thenReturn( // get some Person objects in a List
        Arrays.asList(new Person(1L, "StackOverflow"), new Person(1L,
                "StackOverflow")));
```

and perform the new request with a `Matcher` that does a check appropriate to the elements you return in your `List`. For example

```
mockMvc.perform(get("/persos"))
        .andExpect(status().isOk())
        .andExpect(view().name("personsPage"))
        .andExpect(
                model().attribute(
                        "personList",
                        Matchers.everyItem(AllOf.allOf(
                                HasPropertyWithValue.hasProperty("id", Is.is(1L)),
                                HasPropertyWithValue.hasProperty("name", Is.is("StackOverflow"))))));
```

Answer (score 4):

```
@Autowired
private PersonController personController;

private MockHttpServletRequest request;
private MockHttpServletResponse response;
private PersonService personService;

@Before 
public void setup() { 
    request = new MockHttpServletRequest();
    response = new MockHttpServletResponse(); 
    personService = createNiceMock(PersonService.class);
}
@Test
public void shouldCheckRequestMappingForUserDashBoard() throws Exception {
    request.setRequestURI("/index");
    request.setMethod("GET");
    modelAndView = new AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter().handle(request, response, personController);

    // you can call according to what you want to create mock.
    expect(personService.getPerson()).andReturn(new Person());
    replay(personService);

    Assert.assertNotNull(modelAndView.getViewName());
    Assert.assertEqual(modelAndView.getViewName(),"personPage");
}
```